# Prevent OpenSSL from using system certificates?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

How can I prevent OpenSSL (specifically, Python's `ssl` module) from using system certificate authorities?

In other words, I would like it to trust only the certificate authorities which I specify, and nothing else:

```
ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True, certfile="my_cert.pem",
                             ca_certs=MY_TRUSTED_CAs, # <<< Only CAs specified here
                             cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
```

Comment: Why? This kind of thing usually arises when you try to make authentication do the work of authorization. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @EJP, this can be useful if you don't want the `certificate_authorities` list in the `CertificateRequest` TLS message (the one that requests the client certificate) to include the list you don't want (this list of DNs tends to be populated from the list of available CAs by default). In addition, there might be default CAs on your system you don't trust, even for authentication only.

Comment: I'm using SSL to authenticate clients on a “closed” network: I (well, my CA) will be signing all of their certificates, so there is no reason to trust any other CA.

Comment: @Bruno: what is the meaning, in security terms, of 'default CAs on your system that you don't trust'? If you don't trust them, they shouldn't be there.

Comment: @David Wolever: do you have a reason *not* to trust them?

Comment: @EJP: because there is no reason they *should* be signing certificates used on my closed network, they constitute a security hole.

Comment: @EJP, I meant "default CAs" in the sense of CAs installed by default by the distribution/OS/browser. It's not because a distribution chooses to bundle a CA certificate that you must keep it in your trusted anchors without reviewing it, even if it's what most people do (in fact, the Java Secure Socket Extension reference guide explicitly recommends people who install Java to review what it bundles, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

I've just run a few tests, and listing your selection of CAs in the `ca_certs` parameters is exactly what you need.

The system I've tried it on is Linux with Python 2.6. If you don't use `ca_certs`, it doesn't let you use `cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sockettest.py", line 18, in <module>
    cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 350, in wrap_socket
    suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 113, in __init__
    cert_reqs, ssl_version, ca_certs)
ssl.SSLError: _ssl.c:317: No root certificates specified for verification of other-side certificates.
```

I've also tried to use a client to send a certificate that's not from a CA in the `ca_certs` parameter, and I get `ssl_error_unknown_ca_alert` (as expected).

Note that either way, there's no client-certificate CA list send (in the `certificate_authorities` list in the `CertificateRequest` TLS message), but that wouldn't be required. It's only useful to help the client choose the certificate.

Comment: But, when the client sends a cert, is the CA trusted by your system? ie, if `MY_PERSONAL_CA`'s certificate is trusted by the system (in my case, I've added it to the OS X system keychain… Not sure off the top of my head what the Linux equivalent is) and `ca_certs = [ TESTING_CA ]`, then I've found that a certificate signed by *either* `MY_PERSONAL_CA` *or* `TESTING_CA` will be accepted. This was Python 2.6 on OS X 10.6.

Comment: So, I suppose, if Linux *doesn't* have a central list of trusted CAs (like the OS X keychain), this is only an issue on OS X? (and, since my embedded systems *aren't* going to be running OS X, safe for me to ignore).

Comment: A friend suggested that `/usr/share/ca-certificates` is the central repository used by some Linux distros… When I get a chance, I'll see what happens with that.